# Collider2D. Как узнать локальные точки столкновения (Сollision2D) относительно объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Как узнать точки столкновения `collision2D` относительно `BoxCollider2D`? Как узнать не глобальные, а локальные координаты столкновения относительно объекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `transform.InverseTransformPoint` для перевода мировых координат в локальные

```
var locPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(contact.point);
```